# SQL ignoring where condition in having clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, having

Actually SQL is ignoring the where condition in my having clauses. It doesn't matter what  I fill in there. It always finds "all" results.

```
SELECT `status`, count(*) AS count
FROM `wa_re_jo`
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM `ad_ac_wa`
        WHERE `plattform` = 'adwords'
        AND `wa_re_jo`.`watchlist_id` = `ad_ac_wa`.`id`
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM `ad_cu_ac`
            WHERE `ad_ac_wa`.`external_id` = `ad_cu_ac`.`externalId`
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM `ç`
                WHERE `ad_cu_ac`.`id` = `ad_cu_ac`.`adwords_customer_account_id`
                AND `startDate` <= '2023-04-04'
                AND `endDate` + interval 1 DAY >= '2023-04-04'
            )
        )
    )
AND `created_at` LIKE '2023-04-04%'
OR `updated_at` LIKE '2023-04-04%'
GROUP BY `status`
```

I tried to change the values and the order of the conditions.

Comment: Not sure on your full structure or performance, but have you tried changing these to INNER JOINS?

Comment: Where are the HAVING clauses?

Comment: Which of the 4 (four) `WHERE`-clauses are you taking about, and which `HAVING`-clause (I do not find any one....)

Comment: Add parenthasis around the AND and OR to aid correct interpratation `( AND \`created_at\` LIKE '2023-04-04%' OR \`updated_at\` LIKE '2023-04-04%')`

Comment: Do you store dates in character columns? Use a proper date/time data type instead.

Answer (score 1):

Separate from the fact **there is no `HAVING` clause anywhere in the posted code,** the problem is almost certainly the `OR` conditional expression:

```
AND `created_at` LIKE '2023-04-04%'
OR `updated_at` LIKE '2023-04-04%'
```

You probably want a set of parentheses, like this:

```
AND (`created_at` LIKE '2023-04-04%'
OR `updated_at` LIKE '2023-04-04%')
```

With the original code, matching just the right side of the `OR` clause was enough to match the **entire** `WHERE` clause. That is, it was as if you had written the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE
  (  EXISTS ( ...    )
      AND `created_at` LIKE '2023-04-04%'
   )
  OR `updated_at` LIKE '2023-04-04%'
```

I'll add that, thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, using string expressions to do date comparisons is pretty much always the slowest and most error-prone approach possible. You **WILL** get better and faster results by re-working those comparisons to use **real** date expressions, rather than the **fake** date expressions it's using right now.

---

Finally, when I see multiple levels of `EXISTS()` conditions like this, it's usually a sign something should be re-written to use a `JOIN` instead.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on what you mean by "real" and "fake" date expressions? I'm interested in seeing if I can improve my date filtering.

Comment: @UncleCarl "fake" is anything that treats date values as strings. For example, even if the question's `updated_at` field is stored as a datetime, the DB will have to convert that value to a string for the LIKE comparison. It will do that for **every row in the table**, and it won't be able to use any indexes to help. But if you instead use `updated_at >= '2023-04-04' AND updated_at < '2023-04-05'`, now the database is able to interpret those boundaries as date literals. No conversion happens at all on the values in the database, and it's able to use indexes. **MUCH** better performance.